# C# - Calculate relative angle(0-180) between 2 angles(0-360 and 0-360)?

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, angle, algebra

Im trying to find the relative angle between 2 given angles:

For example:
Angle A: 280degrees
Angle B: 80degrees

Relative angle = 160 degrees

OR

Angle A: 200degrees
Angle B: 010Degrees

relative angle:170degrees

Always finding the signed angle, not going the long way around.

This is what I came up with, but it doesnt work somehow.

```
float GetRelativeAngle(float mainAngle, float secondaryAngle)
{
    float rel = ((secondaryAngle - mainAngle + 180) % 360) - 180;

    if (rel < -180)
    {
        rel += 360;
    }
    return rel;
}
```

Im trying to calculate the relative angle between my ship heading Angle A and the wind direction Angle B.

```
public float GetSpeedFromWindAngle(float mastAngle, bool isSquare)
{
    float angle = GetRelativeAngle(mastAngle, _windAngle);
    float absAngle = Mathf.Abs(angle);
    float magnitudeAngle = absAngle / 180;
    float speedfromAngle = 0f;
    if (isSquare)
        speedfromAngle = _speedFromWindAngleCurveSquares.Evaluate(magnitudeAngle);
    else speedfromAngle = _speedFromWindAngleCurveStays.Evaluate(magnitudeAngle);

    return speedfromAngle;
}
```

magnitudeAngle should be between 0 and 1, so I can use it to evaluate a curve and get a speed from the curve using that magnitude. This also means I dont care if the angle is -150 or +150 so I always use Absolute.

Thank you.

Edit: The script works fine actually all angles debug correctly now and I didnt even change anything :/

Comment: Can you give some specific pairs of angles that go wrong?

Comment: I would highly recommend to create an actual Angle-type. It is super easy to get confused about radians/degrees otherwise.

Comment: doctorlove Thank you for the reply, I debugged again, and this time all rel angles are correct between -180 and 180 as expected. I dont know why it was bugging in the first place though, but it works now :)

Comment: JonasH How would i do  that? Using a struct you mean?

Comment: Why use 180°? You never want to deal with half circles, do you? What about `(secondaryAngle - mainAngle + 360) % 360`?

Comment: Thomas Weller, Its for a sailing ship, so wether the wind is blowing into the sail from -170 or from 170 doesnt matter, that way its easier to normalize aswell, between 0 and 1. instead of trying to normalize 170 and 190 both back to about 0.96f

Comment: `GetRelativeAngle()` looks dodgy.  Consider  `float rel = (secondaryAngle - mainAngle) % 360;  if (rel < -180) rel += 360; else if (rel >= 180) rel -= 360; return rel;`

Comment: I think `GetRelativeAngle(float mastAngle, bool isSquare) { return Math.IEEERemainder(mastAngle - isSquare, 360); }` works even better.